# TableViewCell Swipe left to right and change content in DataBase table(CoreData)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, core-data

I am new in IOS. And sorry for my week english, That time facing a problem. My problem is that I am using a CoreData in my project. In my project TableViewCell scroll left to right. Swipe is proper but I want to That cell are swiped and change database value. Particular indexpath.row are swipe and same row content change in DataBase table.

TableViewCell swipe by SWTableViewCell [This Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/swipeable-uitableviewcell-tutorial/)

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state{
if(state ==1){
 NSLog(@"animation start");
 }
else
NSLog(@"animation end");
 }
```

I am so tried many days but do not update DataBase table in same row on TableViewCell swipe, How can i do this, please help, ThankYou

[image: Swipe my TableView Image]

## Update answer

```
  - (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state{
if(state ==1){
 NSIndexPath *indexPaths = [self.table_view indexPathForCell:cell];
    
    NSManagedObject *selectedDevices = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[self.table_view indexPathForCell:cell].row];
    NSLog(@"device %@",selectedDevices);
    [selectedDevices setValue:@"OnTime" forKeyPath:@"time"];
    
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError];
    if (saveError)
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
        
        
    }
 }
```

Comment: show the `dataSource` of the `TableView`.

Comment: I see that you are setting `pillname`, `doseImg`, and `time` values from `NSManagedObject`. What do you want to do with the `NSManagedObject` when the user swipes?

Comment: @Adeel when the user swipe "time" update. That mean when the user swipe and update current time set in data base table

Comment: Try the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments you need to do follow these simple steps to achieve what you want

1. Set the `tag` of the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method i.e. `cell.tag = indexPath.row` so that you can get the record from `devices` array later
2. In the `delegate` method of cell access the relevant `NSManagedObject` and update the value of `time`
3. Save these changes in the persistent store
4. Reload the cell at `indexPath` you just updated

The code would be something like:

```
NSInteger index = cell.tag;
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:index];
[device setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"tine"];
NSError *error;

if ([context save:&error]) {
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: reason: '-[NSIndexPath count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc000000000000016'
Error show bellow

Comment: on which line does the application crash?

Comment: the crash log does not provide enough information about the crash. Can you please tell at which line does the application crash? @DivankKumawat

Comment: Did my answer help? Have your problem been resolved? @DivankKumawat

Comment: No? thanks for give your precious time and right now my self resolve my problem.